# Traefik and Wordpress too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, traefik

I want to use docker for my websites but since I don't have just one domain I wanted to run all my wordpress instances through docker and control them through a reverse proxy.
I have worked on the introduction on the page (see below) step by step and also made so as well as his tutorial how to install and configure traefik. I first tested it with my personal settings which resulted in "Too many redirect" then I also tested the config 1:1 and only adjusted the domain and this again resulted in a "Too many redirect".
Now I wonder where is the problem that it does not work.
The manual is in german but I hope that does not bother.

**Install wordpress in Docker:**

```
https://goneuland.de/wordpress-mehrere-instanzen-auf-einem-server-betreiben-mit-docker-und-traefik/
```

**install traefik and configure:**

```
https://goneuland.de/traefik-v2-reverse-proxy-fuer-docker-unter-debian-10-einrichten/
```

I currently do not directly recognize my error or the error in the instructions on the page. I hope you can help me because it certainly very many have already managed.

About another tutorial I would of course also happy. Main thing a working and logical use of docker and reverse proxy to offer multiple wordpress instances on one server.

Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: You have probably defined twice the `BASE_URL` for your Wordpress instance, so Traefik is sending you to the Wordpress instance which is redirecting you again to Traefik through a HTTP Redirect. Check the `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` environment variable.

Comment: @DanielCampos Hey, Thanks for your answer but i didnt set the WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA only the WORDPRESS_DB_ Things